# Given a list of arara compilation commands, at which step/s should I use "shell : yes" option?

Tags: shell-escape, arara

In case you need to run a complex compilation command list with `arara`, I know that `synctex: yes` is necessary only at the last step, for example:

```
% arara: pdflatex
% arara: frontespizio
% arara: biber
% arara: pdflatex
% arara: pdflatex: { synctex: yes }
```

But if I need the `shell : yes` option, for example because I'm using `tikzexternalize`, at which point/s should I put it?

Here a mwe:

```
% arara: pdflatex: { shell : yes }
% arara: biber
% arara: pdflatex: { shell : yes }
% arara: pdflatex: { shell : yes , synctex: yes }
\documentclass[11pt,openright]{book}
\usepackage[T1]{fontenc}
\usepackage[latin9]{inputenc}
\usepackage[british]{babel} 

\usepackage{tikz}
\usetikzlibrary{external}
\tikzexternalize[prefix={Figures/}] % activate!

\usepackage[style=authoryear-icomp, backend=biber,hyperref=true]{biblatex} 
\usepackage{csquotes} 
\usepackage{hyperref} 

\addbibresource{biblatex-examples.bib} 

\begin{document}

    \begin{tikzpicture}
        \fill[green] (0,0) rectangle (1,1);
    \end{tikzpicture}

    \cite{aristotle:rhetoric}
    \printbibliography

\end{document}
```

Comment: My guess: on the first run should be more then enough. In theory you should only need it if the figure is not yet existing or you changed something in the figure [assuming the figure itself does not contain any references or similar]

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I saved your file as `test.tex` (and removed the prefix for the figure files, but it's irrelevant).

Then I ran

```
pdflatex -shell-escape test
pdflatex test
```

which gave no problem. The second run issues the message

```
===== Image 'test-figure0' is up-to-date. ======
```

which confirms my statement.

Thus I conclude that `shell: yes` is only needed for the first batch run, leading to

```
% arara: pdflatex { shell: yes }
% arara: frontespizio
% arara: biber
% arara: pdflatex
% arara: pdflatex: { synctex: yes }
```

You would have problems if some TikZ picture contains `\ref` or `\cite`, but this is independent of `arara` and always running `pdflatex` with the `-shell-escape` option would not cure it.

On the other hand, other packages needing `-shell-escape` might behave differently, so there's no general rule, I'm afraid.